# Python Regex to find everything within parenthesis, with a prefix beforehand

Tags: python, regex, python-re

This seems like a fairly simple issue, but I can't get it to work.

I have a text file, which contains JSON like data, but there are a couple of additional lines, stopping it being a valid JSON and I need to remove these. This sounds very simple and even more so, as the valid JSON strings (which I can parse later) are always contained in the following container:

xyz()

So for example, the dataset will be something like:

```
abcdefg
xyz({"id_value": 123, "text_value": "efg"})

abcdefg
xyz({"id_value": 124, "text_value": "hij"})
```

Each separate JSON string is always prefixed by abcdefg and then xyz( and there is always a closing bracket after. So the format is consistent.

I was trying the following:

```
re.findall(r'xyz\(.*?\)', text_file)
```

However despite attempting variations of this (e.g. using re.search, trying \w+ etc.) nothing seems to work (by which I mean it returns an empty list).

If I just try to do the following:

```
re.findall(r'xyz\(
```

Then it returns:

```
['xyz(', 'xyz(']
```

As expected.

So the issue appears to be with the string in the brackets, but I can not work out what the problem is, as other examples on here suggest my code is correct (which it can't be as it doesn't work)!

I presume its something horrifically simple, but I'm a bit stuck!

Comment: `re.findall(r'xyz\((.*?)\)', text_file)` works for me when text_file is a locally defined string. What is text_file in your case?

Comment: Works for me, too.

Comment: This is the frustrating part! It is one of those situations when I can't replicate here (I'm not permitted to post the actual file), but the structure is identical to the above, so it makes no sense (for the avoidance of doubt the file is a local text file)!

Comment: And what about `re.findall(r'xyz\(.*?\)', text_file, re.DOTALL)`?

Comment: Ah, that gets close, for some reason it seems to  cut off randomly using the real live data, but it appears to be (almost) working!

I also have come up with a separate approach not using regex, which I will post as soon as I've completed it!

Comment: You probably want `import regex` (after `pip install regex`) and then `[x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'xyz(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))', text_file)`

Comment: That did indeed work, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install PyPi `regex` module by running `pip install regex` (or `pip3 install regex`) and then using this library to match strings between `xyz(` and the next paired `)` char using:

```py
import regex 
#...
output = [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'xyz(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))', text_file)
```

The list comprehension is used to avoid the issue with `regex.findall` when only captured substrings are returned when a capturing group is defined in the regex (and here, the capturing group around parentheses is required since it is recursed inside the pattern with a `(?1)` subroutine.

*Pattern details*:

- `xyz` - `xyz` text
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1:

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of one or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the subroutine repeats (recurses) the whole Group 1 pattern
  - `\)` - a `)` char.